# Set document field if only does not exists mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

i have a mongodb document which i want to set a field if does not exists otherwise if the field exists i want to keep it as it is, i don't know what is wrong with my code:

```js
     await UserAnalytics.findOneAndUpdate(
      { user },
      {
        $inc: {
          nbPosts: 1,
        },
      },
      {
        $cond: [
          { bestPost: { $exists: false } },
          { $set: { bestPost: newPost._id } },
          { $set: { bestPost: "$bestPost" } },
        ],
      }
    );
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it with Aggregation framework. In order to use Aggregation framework in the update query, you need to wrap second input with `[]`:

```js
db.collection.update({
  user: 1
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "nbPosts": {
        "$sum": [
          "$nbPosts",
          1
        ]
      },
      "bestPost": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$eq": [
              "$bestPost",
              undefined
            ]
          },
          "then": "new_id",
          "else": "$bestPost"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/O_YqTOry_gt)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i tried exactly the same code but it tells me that collection.update is deprecated. when i tried updateOne nothing changes in my database. could you tell me what could be wrong ?

Comment: After some tests i figured out that the problem was in this line "$eq":["$bestPost",undefined] so i set bestPost by default to null in userAnalyticsSchema and changed the test $eq":["$bestPost",null] and that's worked although i don't know why undefined did not do the job when the field does not exists . Anyway Thanks for your help !